# Change font size of comments in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way of having a different font size **just for the comments** in Visual Studio 2010, without the use of any third party tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the default font face, size, and colors

1. Select Options from the Tools menu, and in the Environment folder, select Fonts and Colors.

   The Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box opens.
2. In Show settings for, select Text Editor.
3. Modify the Font and Size options to change the font face and size for all text elements in all editors.
4. Select the appropriate item in Display items, and then modify the Item foreground and Item background options.
5. Click OK

Comment: if you change colors and select Bold for Comment and Bookmarks, other types of text elements will be unaffected.

Comment: When I change the font size it gets changed for all text elements. How do I apply the change only for the comments?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx try going through this link. It clearly says that only particulars are handled

Comment: It says that Font and Size are global for all text elements. :-( Anyways thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The font size is global in VS2010.

You may want to look at this extension however:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/17c68951-7743-40bd-ad35-608706f54a92